# Theme changes in flexdashboard once you use DT::datatable()

Tags: r, dt, flexdashboard

When outputting a simple data frame through DT, my theme change. I've created a reprex below that shows it working correctly (first reprex) and incorrectly (second reprex) once I pipe mtcars to datatable().

Can anyone offer up any insight as to why this is happening?

````
---
title: "Reprex1"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
```

###
```{r}
# Outputs to dashboard correctly with 'bootstrap' theme
mtcars 
```
````

Piping mtcars to DT::datatable() changes the theme of the flexdashboard

````
---
title: "Reprex2"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
```

###
```{r}
# Changes flexdashboard theme
mtcars %>% DT::datatable()
```
````

**Update:**
After troubleshooting this further, it seems like I can use version 3 options of bootswatch themes by entering this:

```
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme:
      version: 3
      bootswatch: spacelab
```

Doesn't allow for the bootstrap theme though...

Comment: I added your `spacelab` option and got the `mtcars %>% DT::datatable()` output as you prescribed, is this issue resolved due to your own research, or do you still have an outstanding question for this SOF question?

Comment: Hi @DanielJachetta - Adding `spacelab` was a bit of a workaround. My preference would be to have the Reprex2 chunk work with the `bootstrap` theme instead of `spacelab` which doesn't seem to work for me. Wondering if this is isolated to my setup or if this is a broader 'issue' ...